# General question about LateX and doctoral thesis

Tags: latex-misc

Hi guys I am new here.

I am PhD student at the pharmacognosy and started learning/writing in LaTeX two months ago, for practice. Even though I do not have many math formula I gave a latex a chance, because writing in Word is so annoying, it crashes every time after 30 pages. So my question is, from a LaTeX expert perspective, is it good to start slow in LaTeX and in the end write thesis in it, or are there easier ways/better programs to write with?

Comment: Welcome to this SE! I would really encourage you to start learning LaTeX. It will definitely make your life a lot easier, especially when writing larger documents. Next to formulae, it also offers a lot of other advantages (scientific drawings, document construction, ...).

Comment: LaTeX is very good to write a thesis. I can recommend [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/) for a good start. For the advanced stuff, have a look at [LaTeX to write a thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! :) So I will then stick to LaTeX ^^

Comment: You might also like LyX from www.lyx.org. I did.

Comment: Yes, it worth the time. With or without math formulas, if you have time and patience to learn, LaTeX will be good to write **anything**, not only your thesis.  First learn the basics of LaTeX with some LaTeX editor and then  try LyX. The learning process is often the inverse, but in this way you will understand faster what LyX is and if this is worth  for you.

Comment: Before you close this..Thank you very much for all the answers! I am trying with it and i did not have any problems until i have stucked with utf8x which is not compatible with bibtex...any suggestions? I downloaded a template and there was utfx8 loaded but no citations, so i have no idea what can I do?
Thanks
Best
Ivana